# $1 + 1/4 + 1/9 + 1/16 + .... + 1/n^2 < 2 - \frac{1}{n}$ for all $n \ge 2$ , $n \in N$.

Tags: inequality, summation

I proved this inequality using mathematical induction. I was wondering if it can be proved in any other way. Please help me.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: @Norse How comes a geometric series into play here ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the fact that\begin{align}\require{cancel}1+\frac1{2^2}+\cdots+\frac1{n^2}&<1+\frac1{1\times2}+\frac1{2\times3}+\cdots+\frac1{(n-1)\times n}\\&=1+1-\cancel{\frac12}+\cancel{\frac12}-\cancel{\frac13}+\cancel{\frac13}+\cdots-\frac1n\\&=2-\frac1n.\end{align}

Answer (score 4):

For example you can prove this by integration. For $n > 1$
$$
\sum\limits_{i = 1}^{n} \frac{1}{i^2} < 1 + \int\limits_{1}^n\frac{dx}{x^2} = 1 + (- \frac{1}{x})|_1^n = 2 - \frac{1}{n}
$$

Comment: A nice proof. (+1)